# Preenchimento em Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Bom dia, tenho um data frame com temperatura do ar, radiação global e CO2, porém meus dados de CO2 estão com `NaN` e preciso encontrar dados em outras "linhas" com semelhança para preencher o Nan pelo dado de CO2.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_hdf('./dados.hd5')

df.head()

Year_DoY_Hour          Tair        Rg       CO2
2016-01-01 00:00:00    22.651600   0.000    NaN
2016-01-01 00:30:00    22.445700   0.000    6.43
2016-01-01 01:00:00    22.388300   0.000    5.03
2016-01-01 01:30:00    22.400000   0.000    3.05
2016-01-01 02:00:00    22.257099   0.000    NaN
2016-01-01 02:30:00    22.133900   0.000    2.50
2016-01-01 03:00:00    21.948999   0.000    1.58
2016-01-01 03:30:00    21.787901   0.000    0.89
2016-01-01 04:00:00    21.610300   0.000    1.58
2016-01-01 04:30:00    21.619400   0.000    NaN
```

Comment: O que seria estas linhas "com semelhança"? Ter temperatura e radiação global com valores próximos?

Comment: Tenho um df grande, por isso preciso encontrar a linha que mais se assemelha para substituir o valor do CO2 no arquivo Nan.

Comment: E qual o conceito de semelhança entre as linhas que deseja?

Comment: Onde não tiver dados de CO2 procurar dados semelhantes com o de Tair e Rg, para que naquela linha seja preenchido o dado do CO2 com um dado parecido.

Comment: Mas no seu arquivo em disco - .hd5 - os valores são o texto "NaN" mesmo? Ou será que só aconeceu do Pandas não conseguir ler alguns dos valores devido a uma formataçao diferente?

Comment: qual o tamanho da série de dados? Pode dar pra fazer com sort com uma função `key` que ordene pela distância de um dado valor  - mas teria que ordenar uma vez para cada número que quiser recuperar.  Outra forma é colocar o tair como indice numa estrutura de árvore binária.

Comment: Sim, os valores do texto são "NaN".

Comment: O tamanho da minha série de dados é de 1 ano com dados a cada meia hora.

Answer (score 1):

Parece-me que, pela descrição do seu problema, que você está diante de um problema preditivo, e mais precisamente, trata-se do problema de consertar os valores incompletos de um conjunto de dados valendo-se da informação contida nele mesmo. É um problema comum e conhecido na literatura de ciência de dados e as sugestões, em geral, são de tratar o problema como um problema de classificação ou regressão normal onde as variáveis alvos serão as variáveis com valores incompletos as quais você deseja completar.

Existem outras formas aconselhadas na literatura para tratar valores incompletos, por exemplo, as técnicas resumidas [aqui](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/jf/ch14.pdf). Porém, visto que você já se decidiu por tentar prever os valores incompletos por similaridade, este [link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/) traz um exemplo fácil de como implementar um modelo de Análise Discriminativa Linear (Linear Descriminant Analysis) para este fim, usando a biblioteca de aprendizado de máquina [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/). Transcrevo a parte específica do código abaixo:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
dataset = read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', header=None)
# mark zero values as missing or NaN
dataset[[1,2,3,4,5]] = dataset[[1,2,3,4,5]].replace(0, numpy.NaN)
# split dataset into inputs and outputs
values = dataset.values
X = values[:,0:8]
y = values[:,8]
# fill missing values with mean column values
imputer = Imputer()
transformed_X = imputer.fit_transform(X)
# evaluate an LDA model on the dataset using k-fold cross validation
model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=7)
result = cross_val_score(model, transformed_X, y, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
print(result.mean())
```